# Assembling a String List using a Markov-method hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm given a hashmap with keys of string lists with two strings and values of string lists with varying amount of strings. I have to assemble and return a string list of the values of the hashmap, except in the case where the value contains more than one string, in which case the element should be a random string out of the list.

In other words, a map of `<[a, b], b> | <[b, c], d> | <[c, d], [e, f, g]> | <[d, e], f>` (where each letter is a string) would return a String list of the elements `[b, d, x, f]` where x is either e, f, or g, chosen randomly. <strike>It can also be assumed that the first key in the map is a String list of length 2 where both elements are "", and the final value is a String list of length 1 containing ""</strike> (see bottom). Below is the code.

```
  static ArrayList<String> generateText(Map<List<String>, List<String>> whatComesNext, Random r) {
    List<List<String>> listKey = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    int x;
    ret.add("<START>");
    ret.add("<START>");
    for (List<String> key : whatComesNext.keySet())
        listKey.add(key);
    for (int i=0; i<whatComesNext.size()-1; i++)
      if (listKey.get(i).size()>1) {
        x=r.nextInt(listKey.get(i).size());
        ret.add(listKey.get(i).get(x)); }
      else ret.add(listKey.get(i).get(0));
    return ret;
  }
```

The problem here is that it's supposed to pass tests from a separate program via AssertEquals and such. The problem is I'm getting an assertionerror, saying "Doesn't match aa". I can't understand what it's expecting, and I can't see how my program doesn't return what I specified above. The relevant lines are:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ab)+c");
    int [] histogram = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
      List<String> result = MarkovText.generateText(whatComesNext, new Random(197*i));
      result = MarkovText.excludeStartAndEndMarkers(result);
      assertEquals(1, result.size() % 2);
      int repeats = (result.size()-1)/2;
      if (repeats < histogram.length)
        histogram[repeats] = histogram[repeats]+1;
      StringBuffer together = new StringBuffer();
      for(String w : result) 
        together.append(w);
      assertTrue("Doesn't match " + together, pattern.matcher(together).matches());
```

while the rest of the test looks like this.

```
public void testSimpleGeneration() {
    List<String> text =
        Arrays.asList("<START> <START> a b a b c <END>".split(" "));
    Map<List<String>, List<String>> whatComesNext = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    MarkovText.learnFromText(whatComesNext, text);
    System.out.println(whatComesNext);
    assertEquals(5, whatComesNext.size());
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("a", "c"), whatComesNext.get(Arrays.asList("a", "b")));
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(ab)+c");
    int [] histogram = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
      List<String> result = MarkovText.generateText(whatComesNext, new Random(197*i));
      result = MarkovText.excludeStartAndEndMarkers(result);
      assertEquals(1, result.size() % 2);
      int repeats = (result.size()-1)/2;
      if (repeats < histogram.length)
        histogram[repeats] = histogram[repeats]+1;
      StringBuffer together = new StringBuffer();
      for(String w : result) 
        together.append(w);
      assertTrue("Doesn't match " + together, pattern.matcher(together).matches());
    }
    assertEquals(0, histogram[0]);
    assertTrue("expected distribution of results", 32 <= histogram[1] && histogram[1] <= 128 );
    assertTrue("expected distribution of results", 16 <= histogram[2] && histogram[2] <= 64 );
    assertTrue("expected distribution of results", 8 <= histogram[3] && histogram[3] <= 32 );
  }
```

EDIT: The map was created earlier in the program, from a separate given String List. For this part of the program, the List had the following elements: ["[START]", "[START]", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "[END]"] where the every key is a pair of two consecutive elements and the value is the element following the pair.

Comment: _"It can also be assumed that the first key in the map is..."_ -- this indicates a serious problem in your understanding of maps.  A map does not have a "first key" or "last key".  As to your error, unless you provide the input, output and expected output we cannot help. The error is saying the string `"aa"` does not match the regular expression `(ab)+c`, which is a true statement.  Only strings of the form `ab` one or more time followed by `c` will match.  But we don't know what your input was.

Comment: Alright, I know exactly what you mean by the first sentence, I kind of miscommunicated because the map was originally based on a String List input from earlier in the program. I'll add what the input is to the original post.